# Get the div inside another div without using ID attribute in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to access the div with class `formErrorContent` inside the div with id `emailMsg` without putting ID attribute for the inner div. How can I achieve that?

```
<div id="emailMsg" class="formError" style="opacity: 0.80; margin-top: 0px;display:none;" onclick="this.style.display='none';">
  <div class="formErrorContent">* This field is required<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

```
$('#emailMsg').find('.formErrorContent');
```

This could also be written this way;

```
$('#emailMsg .formErrorContent');
```

.. depending on which works best for you.

If you can guarantee that `.formErrorContent` will always be a child, consider using `children()` and the child [selector instead](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector).

Answer (score 2):

Use a class selector...

```
$("#emailMsg div.formErrorContent");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = $('#emailMsg .formErrorContent').text();
```